# Overriding save method raises exception when object is created

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm trying to create an identificator for my Scheduler model which depends on `ManyToManyField` of this model.

The problem is that when I override `save` method, the first time (when object is created) it causes problems. It should be saved first. On the other hand when I create a `post_save` signal, the problem is that I have to `save` the model inside this signal which ends with infi

```
class Scheduler(models.Model):
    weekhours = models.ManyToManyField('WeekHour', related_name='schedulers')
    identificator = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.weekhours.all():
            identificator = ','.join([str(x.hour) for x in self.weekhours.all().order_by('hour')])
            self.identificator = identificator
        super(Scheduler, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> ValueError: `"<Scheduler: None>"` needs to have a value for field "scheduler" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, what about

```
# some logic here (count the identificator)
objects.filter(id=my_id).update(identificator=identificator)
```

in your signal - and do not override the save? :)